# Connecting to Access Database with Sharepoint

Tags: access, database-connection

i'm trying to connect to an Access Database which is located on the desktop's server. 
I tried this :

```
DatabaseAcces dbSAP = new DatabaseAcces(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data   Source=C:\\Users\\adm_sharepoint\\Desktop\\PPMO\\BDD-Access\\BDD_PPMO_SAP.accdb");
DataSet dsCarneOffre = dbSAP.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CarnetOffres");
```

And I try to connect with this function :

```
private void connexionOpen(){
        connect = new OleDbConnection(connexionString);
        connect.Open();
}
```

But when i arrive to the line

```
connect.Open()
```

i get this error :

"The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."
Source="System.Data"

Do you guys have any idea what to do ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint is 64 bit code and can't call 32 bit libraries.

Jet is only 32-bit see [How to get a x64 version of Jet?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/01/21/how-to-get-a-x64-version-of-jet.aspx)

But you may be able to use [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think i'll use sql server then.

Comment: That's an EXCELLENT choice